# meta-qt5 yocto layer not compile on qt release 5.15.2

Tags: yocto, qt5.15

I cannot build my yocto distro (from 'pyro' version) when upgrade the *meta-qt5* to the Qt version **5.15.2**: I checkout the repository of meta-qt5 to the master branch that now support the qt **5.15.2**, but I got some error on configuration about openssl and pcre2.

I'm using a container with ubuntu 18.04 as build system (to have the openssl version 1.1.1 as required by **QT5.15.x**) but I cannot solve that errors during the build of *qtbase* recipe:

```
| ERROR: Feature 'system-pcre2' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.pcre2' failed.
| 
| ERROR: Feature 'openssl-runtime' was enabled, but the pre-condition '!features.securetransport && !features.schannel && libs.openssl_headers' failed.
| WARNING: exit code 3 from a shell command.
```

I tried to comment the pcre and openssl packegeconfig into the qtbase recipe (to workaround that problems) but it didn't solve it.

The configuration return:

```
Configure summary:

Building on: linux-oe-g++ (arm, CPU features: neon)
Building for: linux-oe-g++ (arm, CPU features: neon)
Target compiler: gcc 6.3.0
Configuration: cross_compile compile_examples enable_new_dtags largefile neon silent shared shared release c++11 c++14 concurrent dbus reduce_exports stl
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++14
  Using ccache ........................... no
  Using new DTAGS ........................ yes
  Relocatable ............................ yes
  Using precompiled headers .............. no
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    NEON ................................. yes
  Build parts ............................ libs tests tools
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... yes
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... yes
  udev ................................... yes
  Using system zlib ...................... yes
  Zstandard support ...................... no
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
  GLib ................................... no
  iconv .................................. no
  ICU .................................... no
  Built-in copy of the MIME database ..... yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  PCRE2 .................................. no
    Using system PCRE2 ................... no
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... yes
  IPv6 ifname ............................ yes
  libproxy ............................... no
  Linux AF_NETLINK ....................... yes
  OpenSSL ................................ no
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ no
  DTLS ................................... no
  OCSP-stapling .......................... no
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
  GSSAPI ................................. no
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ yes
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ no
  Fontconfig ............................. no
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. no
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... yes
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ yes
  Text formats:
    HtmlParser ........................... yes
    CssParser ............................ yes
    OdfWriter ............................ yes
    MarkdownReader ....................... yes
      Using system libmd4c ............... no
    MarkdownWriter ....................... yes
  EGL .................................... yes
  OpenVG ................................. yes
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ yes
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... no
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. yes
  libinput ............................... no
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. no
  tslib .................................. no
  xkbcommon .............................. no
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. no
    XCB Xlib ............................. no
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
    xkbcommon-x11 ........................ no
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. yes
  EGLFS details:
    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... yes
    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no
    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... no
    EGLFS GBM ............................ no
    EGLFS VSP2 ........................... no
    EGLFS Mali ........................... no
    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no
    EGLFS X11 ............................ no
  LinuxFB ................................ no
  VNC .................................... no
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... no
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... yes
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes

Note: Overriding option 'eglfs' with 'yes' (was: 'no')

Note: -hostbindir is not a subdirectory of -hostprefix.
Note: -hostlibdir is not a subdirectory of -hostprefix.
Note: -hostdatadir is not a subdirectory of -hostprefix.

ERROR: Feature 'system-pcre2' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.pcre2' failed.

ERROR: Feature 'openssl-runtime' was enabled, but the pre-condition '!features.securetransport && !features.schannel && libs.openssl_headers' failed.
WARNING: exit code 3 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /yocto/pyro/build/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-mx6sx-fslc-linux-gnueabi/qtbase/5.15.2+gitAUTOINC+40143c189b-r0/temp/log.do_configure.1849)
```

Comment: The openssl library on your host system absolutely does not matter to Yocto. openssl 1.1 recipe does not exist on pyro. You'll need to either backport an openssl1.1 recipe from a newer version of Yocto (but that'll very likely break all the other packages dependening on openssl 1.0) or just upgrade your Yocto to a version that supports QT 5.15.2. Having layers aimed at different versions of Yocto is not officially supported in Yocto so you'll be probably on your own trying to do this, especially using such an old version of Yocto and such a recent version of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OpenSSL of honister (or any other poky that uses OpenSSL 1.1.x) and overwrite the prefered version of openssl in `poky/meta/conf/distro/include/default-versions.inc`.
Could be that you have to change the new Yocto x:append syntax back to the old x_append, depending on what Yocto version you take the OpenSSL recipe from.